# Need to edit wp simple paypal cart to update price based on drop down option

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the [wp simple paypal cart](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/ecommerce/simple-wp-shopping-cart-installation-usage-290) for my site.  I know you can do say [wp_cart:Demo Product 1:price:15:var1[Size|Small|Medium|Large]:end] to get a drop down of options when adding to the cart, but I want the price to be updated depending on what option I choose.  I am quite handy with php so I would be comfortable getting the values and updating the $price variable, but I can't really see where the options are in the wp-shopping-cart.php file to add name values to them.

So has anyone else had any luck with editing it to update the price based on options chosen in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

well, are you sure that simple paypal cart isn't able to give different variations of a product different prices ? has been a big issue in wordpress ecommerce back in the old days. maybe you should check http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/multiple-pricing-in-simple-paypal-shopping-cart

Answer (score 0):

I was going to try to hack the ReadForm function but instead I wrote a little java script snippet called CheckSize that I hung off the onsubmit inside the form command right after the ReadForm function puts the form data into variables.

In the wp_shopping_cart.php file I modified onsubmit to read as follows
--> onsubmit="ReadForm(this, true);CheckSize (this, true); <--

The ReadForm function puts small, medium or large into the variable called "variation1" and price into a variale called "price" so in the CheckSize function I test the value of variation1 and change the price variable accordingly if they select size medium or large.

I edited the theme's header.php file and put a JavaScript call to my price.js file (that contains only the CheckSize function below) in front of the /head tag so my function gets loaded when any page in that theme gets loaded.

My function is pasted below (the entire contents of price.js).  The default base price is the price for a small sized item which in my case is $20.  If they select medium, I add $15 to the small price.  If they select large, I add $30 to the small price.  This works for me because all my products are $20 for the small size but this code could be modified very easily to multiply the base price by a percentage for medium and large which would make it more flexible if your products had different base prices.  (ie medium could be 150% of small price and large could be 200% of small price)

```
// --

function CheckSize(form_name) {

// dump any variable for checking contents next
// alert('Price:' + form_name.price.value);
// return false; 

// next set price to a numeric variable value of 0
var price= new Number; 
// next set price to base price times 1 so it doesn't become a string variable
price=form_name.price.value*1; 

// size medium price adjustment is next
if(form_name.variation1.value=='medium') 
{ 
form_name.price.value=price+15;
}

// size large price adjustment is next
if(form_name.variation1.value=='large') 
{ 
form_name.price.value=price+30;
}

// dump any variable for checking contents next
// alert('Price:' + form_name.price.value);
// return false; 

} // end of function CheckSize()

// --
```

The placement of the call to this code above (onsubmit) causes it to be executed after the variables are "busted" by the ReadForm function but before they are sent to the cart.  I'm an old mainframe guy who's just winging it so I hope my terminology doesn't throw you. I learned enough about JavaScript yesterday to do what I had to do so it might look sloppy to an expert.  My apologies if it makes you cringe.

Sheff